# Unable to locate elements which really exist in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

unable to locate element in selenium. that is actually a shopify App on shopify store developed using python. when ever i try to select any element on app error appearing unable to locate element

```
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navbar"]/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

front end code

```
<td class="text-start"><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-dots-vertical theme--light"></i></span></button><div class="v-menu"><!----></div></td>
```

Trying to select this mentioned in screen shot

[image]

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks  -- You may have to [WAIT](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) until element is clickable...

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't rely on `sleep()`, use [`Waits`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)
2. Do you see any `<a>` in your "front end code"? Neither do I. It's just impossible to select the thing that does not exists, you know :)
3. Do you really need your selector to be this complicated?

   ```xml
   //*[@id="navbar"]/div/ul/li[2]/a
   ```

   Or is it possible to use sort of a `class` or `id` instead?
4. What will happen if you won't click on a specific `<a>` and will try to click a whole list entry?

   It's usually enough to click some outer element instead of
   complecating XPath selector more and more.